# Netty, где лучше сохранять подключения?

Tags: java, netty

Хочу сделать так что бы каждый коннект работал в своем потоке.
Думал сделать отдельный `ThreadPool`, но при инициализации `ServerBootstrap` я уже создал 2 пула потоков `bossGroup` и `workGroup`.

На сайте Netty сказано что `bossGroup` принимает новые подключения, а `workGroup` работает с трафиком.
Может как то можно использовать для запуска потоков коннектов `workGroup` или лучше создать отдельный пул потов для этого?

Comment: Это как бы всю концепцию NIO нарушает, нет смысла на каждое подключение делать отдельный поток.

Comment: А что тогда можно сделать, если мне нужно каждому подключенному клиенту передавать данные и получать от него? Без использования потоков я не представляю как это можно сделать.

Comment: Для передачи/получения данных достаточно рабочих потоков. Далее в хендлере сервера обрабатываете полученные данные, отвечаете или стартуете какую-то работу.

Comment: Допустим по подключению клиент запрашивает данные из БД, которые вытягиваются достаточно долго. Тогда создаете где-нибудь общий ExecutorService с несколькими потоками, при получении запроса в хендлере сервера создаёте Runnable/Callable передав ему Channel и закидываете в ExecutorService, всё - хендлер свободен, рабочие потоки тоже, а ваше задание выполняется в отдельном потоке и по завершении отправите ответ в Channel.

Comment: Значит это нормально если я создам класс `Connect` передам в него `Channel` и запущу `Connect` как отдельный поток который будет обслуживать одного клиента?

Comment: В принципе можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается все намного проще чем я думал. при создании сервера создаем два `EventLoopGroup(bossGroup, workerGroup)`.
Например так:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(5);
```

При настройке `ServerBootstrap` нужно добавить обработчики событий которые и будут делать всю работу по коммуникации с клиентом:

```
bootServer.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception{
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(Pack.class.getClassLoader())));
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ConnectionWork());
                }
            });
```

Так как при каждом новом подключении будет вызываться метод `initChannel` то все что мы напишем в `ConnectionWork` будет работать отдельно для каждого подключения, количество подключений задается в конструкторе `workGroup`.